# How delete an object based on its index from a nested array in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I click the icon 'delete' on the product. I pull out his index and save it in state. Example: `select: 1`,`index: 1`.
How to set `this.setState` to delete an object nested in an array `colors` in array `products`. Example delete object:

```
{
  a: 'orange'
}
```

from array `colors` in array `products`

`this.state.select` is the item in the products, `this.state.index` is color in the item to delete

And how does it look in a real application? Give your products and colors id? I would like it to be dynamic. I click the product, download its index and delete

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();

    this.state {
      products: [  
            {
                colors: [{a:'black'}, {a:'orange'}, {a:'purple'}]
                desc: 'gfgfg'
            },
            {
                colors: [{a: 'yellow'}, {a: 'white'}, {a:'gray'}],
                desc: 'gfgfgfg'
            },
            {
                colors: [{a: 'pink'}, {a: 'brown'}, {a:'green'}],
                desc: 'gfgfgfg'
            }
        ],
        select: 1 //example
        index: 1 //example
    }

  }

  removeItem = () => {
    const { select, index } = this.state;

    if(index) {
      this.setState({
          products: [
            ...this.state.products[select].colors.slice(0, index),
            ...this.state.products[select].colors.slice(index + 1),
          ]
      });
    }
  };


  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
            {
                this.state.products
                .map((product, index) =>
                    <Product
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        product={product}
                    />
                )
            }
        </ul>
          <Products

          />
      </div>
    )
  } 
}
```

Comment: So `this.state.select` is the item in the products to be deleted, and `this.state.index` the item under `colors` to be deleted?

Comment: What's the difference between `select` and `index`?

Comment: `this.state.select` is the item in the products, `this.state.index` is color in the item to delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the remove function to `Product` component, in `Product` component pass the select and index to `removeItem` function.

modify your remove item, to take in two parameters, `select` and `index`.

```
removeItem = (select, index) => {

  const filtered = this.state.products[select].colors.filter(
    (color, i) => i !== index
  );

  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      select: select,
      index: index,
      products: [
        ...prevState.products.slice(0, select),
        Object.assign({}, prevState.products[select], { colors: filtered }),
        ...prevState.products.slice(select + 1)
      ]
    };
  });
};
```

Pass the function as prop to `Product` component.

```
<div>
  <ul>
    {this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
      <Product
        key={index}
        index={index}
        removeItem={this.removeItem}
        product={product}
      />
    ))}
  </ul>
</div>
```

In your product component, pass the index of the color and the select.

```
<button onClick={() => removeItem(index, i)}>X</button>
```

**DEMO**

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.21.1/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

class Product extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { product, removeItem, index } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{product.desc}</p>
        <ul>
          {product.colors.map((color, i) => (
            <li>
              {color.a} <button onClick={() => removeItem(index, i)}>X</button>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: "React",
      products: [
        {
          colors: [{ a: "black" }, { a: "orange" }, { a: "purple" }],
          desc: "gfgfg"
        },
        {
          colors: [{ a: "yellow" }, { a: "white" }, { a: "gray" }],
          desc: "gfgfgfg"
        },
        {
          colors: [{ a: "pink" }, { a: "brown" }, { a: "green" }],
          desc: "gfgfgfg"
        }
      ],
      select: 1, //example
      index: 1 //example
    };
  }

    removeItem = (select, index) => {
      const filtered = this.state.products[select].colors.filter(
        (color, i) => i !== index
      );

      this.setState(prevState => {
        return {
          select: select,
          index: index,
          products: [
            ...prevState.products.slice(0, select),
            Object.assign({}, prevState.products[select], { colors: filtered }),
            ...prevState.products.slice(select + 1)
          ]
        };
      });
    };

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
          <Product
            key={index}
            index={index}
            removeItem={this.removeItem}
            product={product}
          />
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
</script>
```

Comment: You are amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Array.filter()` to create a new array not containing the specific element. So your new color array for that desc is:

`this.state.products[select].colors.filter( color => color.a !== 'orange' )`

This keeps all the colors where `a` is not orange.
Keep in mind that arrays are zero-based, so your `select` and `index` should both start at 0.

If you do not want to store the actual indexes, use the desc instead.

So if `select` would be `gfgfg` instead of the array index, you could do:

```js
const state = {
  products: [
      {
          colors: [{a:'black'}, {a:'orange'}, {a:'purple'}],
          desc: 'gfgfg'
      },
      {
          colors: [{a: 'yellow'}, {a: 'white'}, {a:'gray'}],
          desc: 'gfgfgfg'
      },
      {
          colors: [{a: 'pink'}, {a: 'brown'}, {a:'green'}],
          desc: 'gfgfgfg'
      }
  ],
  selected_product: 'gfgfg',
  color: 'orange'
};

const setState = update => Object.assign( state, update );

console.log( 'before update' );
console.log( JSON.stringify( state.products[0] ));

setState({
  products: state.products.map( product => {
    if ( product.desc === state.selected_product ) {
      product.colors = product.colors.filter( color => color.a !== state.color );
    }
    return product;
  })
});

console.log( 'after update' );
console.log( JSON.stringify( state.products[0] ));
```

Same logic can obviously be done using the indexes, but that might result in longer code.
Might have to update some of the code if everything has to be fully immutable.

Comment: This is not what I expected. And how does it look in a real application? Give your products and colorom id? I would like it to be dynamic. I click the product, download its index and delete

Comment: Give all products an unique id, like the id coming from the products database. Include that id as a data attribute. on the row. Find the product again in the collection. I always work by id since that allows me to use basic hyperlinks without the need to add a click events to translate the index back into an actual product identifier.